# Golden Ball vs Golden Boot in FIFA World Cup

Tags: football, world-cup

What is the difference between the Golden Ball and the Golden Boot awarded in the FIFA World Cup?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference between the two is very clearly explained on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFA_World_Cup_awards#Golden_Ball):

> The Golden Ball award is presented to the best player at each FIFA World Cup finals
>
> The Golden Boot [...] Award goes to the top goalscorer of the FIFA World Cup.

(Note that the Wikipedia page is slightly out of date with respect to who votes for the Golden Ball - while in 2010 it was voted for by the media, in 2014 it was voted for by the [Technical Study Group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2014_FIFA_World_Cup#Awards)).